# iPhone delegation bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, getter-setter, delegation

I've got 2 views. The `firstView` and the `secondView`. The `firstView` needs the favourites array from the `secondView`, so I try to call the `getFavourites` method defined in the protocol. This returns null however, which seems strange to me because everything makes sense.

Here is the `firstViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Drink.h"

@protocol firstViewControllerDelegate;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    id <firstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
    NSMutableArray *labels;

    UIButton *button1;
    UIButton *button2;
    UIButton *button3;
    UIButton *button4;
}

- (IBAction) buttonClick: (id) sender;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <firstViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *button4;

@end

@protocol firstViewControllerDelegate
- (NSMutableArray *) getFavourites;
- (void) setFavourites: NSMutableArray;
@end
```

`firstViewController.m`

```
@synthesize delegate;

.......

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSMutableArray *favourites = [delegate getFavourites]; // favourites is empty after this line
    [button1 setTitle:[[favourites objectAtIndex:1] name] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSLog(@"VIEW APPEARED. BUTTON TITLE IS: %@", button1.currentTitle);
}
```

`SecondViewController.h`

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController: UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, firstViewControllerDelegate>
{
        NSMutableArray *favourites;
        NSMutableArray *drinks;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *drinks;
@property (nonatomic, retain, getter = getFavourites) NSMutableArray *favourites;

- (void) addDrink: (NSString *) name;

@end
```

Does anybody have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: Did you check if the delegate is assigned at the time getFavorites is called?

Comment: What do you mean? What do I need to assign it to and how do I assign it?

Comment: Replace the delegate property with `@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController *delegate`, go to the xib, drop a view controller icon, set it to SecondController, and link it to the property. Another way is to instantiate the controller in viewDidLoad. I think you don't quite understand the concept of delegate and controller, but that won't prevent you from getting this working.

Comment: I added the property that you mentioned. I wasn't quite sure how to do the first method, so I followed the second method.

So you'd instantiate it in the viewDidLoad method with UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; and then how would you assign the delegate?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're setting the delegate property of FirstViewController? i.e.:

```
FirstViewController *firstController = // Instantiate the controller;
firstController.delegate = secondController;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:firstController animated:YES];
```

`secondController` should exist before instantiation, otherwise you're setting a `nil` value